# Finding peak frequencies per chunk of recorded audio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fft, frequency-analysis

I am new to android studio and I am still quite inexperienced with Java programming. I have a task to create an application for android devices that records audio and then analyzes the audio to return the peak frequency detected in every chunk (say every 8000 samples or so).

So far, I have managed to implement the recording function in Android Studio, all is left is the peak frequency detection(the audio file is currently mp4 but I can change this).

If anyone could please help by giving me some steps, code or libraries I could look at for finding peak frequency, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

I know that I have to use some form of the FFT, so far I tried TarsosDSP but I could only find methods for pitch detection which is not exactly what I need. I also managed to find some older libraries such as spectro-edit but I could not get it to work in Android Studio.

Comment: Extract the waveform; build the fft yourself. It will be a good exercise ;-)

Comment: Most people seem to use [JTransforms](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms) for this kind of thing.

Comment: Problems like that benefit from being prototyped in higher level languages, e.g. Python (numpy has fft). You can do it in a few lines and play with parameters. Looking at the frequencies every few time steps has a name (short time fourier transform)  or, actually many names ( periodogram , Gabor transform...). See e.g. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html.  Once you have an intuition, programming it in Java will be much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I have successfully managed to implement the peak frequency function in python. However I am experiencing problems in android studio as I discovered that Android does not support wav files. Would it be feasible to create a small web application where the android app uploads an mp4 file to a python web app and the python web app converts this to a wav and applies the fourier transform and finally the results are sent back to the android app.